# Intuition for exponential derivatives

Tags: derivatives, exponential-function, exponentiation, intuition

We have $d/dx(b^x) = b^x\log(b)$, with $b>0$.

If $b < e$, then $b^x > b^x\log(b)$. If $b = e$, then $b^x = b^x\log(b)$. If $b > e$, then $b^x < b^x\log(b)$. In fact, if you take the $Nth$ derivative, as $N$ approaches infinity, the limits are $0$, $b^x$, and $\infty$ respectively.

One might also notice that if you consider a function $a_{n+1} = d/dx(a_n)$, with $a_0=b^x$, then $a_n = b^x\log(b)^n$. This means $a_n$ grows exponentially for $b > e$, but decays for $b < e$.

The math is clear, but I'm having trouble finding the intuition as to why this is. In other words, what is so different about $2.7^x$, $e^x$, and $2.72^x$ that would cause such a drastic change in the acceleration of the derivatives?

Comment: Consider $F(x)=\sin(cx)$. If $|c|<1$, then the $n^{th}$ derivative goes to $0$ as $n\to \infty$, if $c=1$, then it stays at $\sin x$, while if $|c|>1$ then the $n^{th}$ derivative oscillates with larger and larger amplitudes as $n\to \infty$. Does this phenomenon also surprise you? Or more generally, you can do the same thing by starting with an infinitely differentiable function $f$ (whose derivatives are not identically $0$), and considering $F(x)=f(cx)$ for various values of $c$, and you'll find analogous results

Comment: You haven’t covered the case where $b<1,$ where the $N$th derivative alternates in sign.

Comment: @peek-a-boo : For that matter, compare the derivatives of $f(cx)$ and $f(x)$; specifically, $$\frac{\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(cx)}{\frac{d^n}{dx^n} f(x) } = c^n$$

Comment: The important case is that there is one value, $e,$ such that $f(x)=e^x$ satisfies $f’(x)=e^x.$ The rest of the cases follow from this, since $g(x)=b^x=e^{x\log b}$ which we can differentiate by the chain rule.

Comment: @ThomasAndrews The case for $0<b<1$ approaches $0$ as $n -> \infty$. Makes sense, it alternates in sign but the oscillations approach zero.

Comment: @MPW yup, I'm aware, I was just trying to point out to the OP that this was nothing special to the exponential functions, since $b^x= e^{(\log b)x}$, and hence is of the form $f(cx)$. The crucial point here is the scale factor $c$ which repeatedly pops out during the differentiation, and the magnitude of $c$ is what detrmines this qualitative behavior (which in the case of $c=\log b$ translates into whether $0<b<1$ or $b=1$ or $1<b<\infty$).

Comment: Thanks for the thoughts everyone! I believe this is just a "truth", with no real "visual" intuition. A sort of butterfly effect around b=e, which as mentioned happens with many families of functions.

Comment: No, the $n$th derivative in the case $b<1$ approaches zero only if $b>1/e.$ @user2770791 It’s true that if $0<b<1,$ $b^x\to 0$ as $x\to \infty,$ But that wasn’t the question.

Comment: @peek-a-boo : Was just making it painfully explicit